# Finding the composite keys of a table

Tags: composite-key

I have a huge table that i am querying and i just wanted to know how do i find the composite keys of a table as this table does not have a primary key however it contains an auto incremented id.

The table looks like this : 
[image]

I am a beginner to SQL so any help will be appreciated thanks.

Comment: This is an Orders table

Comment: @Coder That's correct it's an orders table